# multiple clave primaria laravel

Tags: laravel

**  hola, soy   nueva   en  laravel  y  quisiera  saber  como  definir  múltiples  claves  primaria  en  laravel, ya que de esta maner me da error  .

Schema::create('horario', function (Blueprint $table) {

```
        $table->string('dia');
        $table->string('hora');
        $table->integer('sala');
        $table->increments('id_asignatura');
        $table->primary(['dia', 'hora', 'sala']);
        $table->foreign('id_asignatura')->references('id_asignatura')->on('asignatura');
        $table->timestamps();
    }); **
```

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente Laravel no soporta claves primarias compuestas.
Tal vez lo mejor sería crear un índice único por esas tres columnas, algo así:

```
$table->unique( array('dia','hora', 'sala') );
```

y crear una clave primaria autoincremental:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->primary('id');
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: De donde tienes ese dato? Cual es la referencia?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes definir tus claves primarias así:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('dia');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('hora');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('sala');
$table->primary(['dia', 'hora', 'sala']);
```